# Is regular TM recognizable?

Tags: complexity-theory, regular-language, automata, computation-theory, turing-machines

What I learned from theorem 5.3, we are dividing the problem into to 1)Language of all strings 2)Not all strings. Where ATM is recognizable but in case when it accepts a word ,modified TM too have to accept all (a loop) but when ATM rejects ,Modified Tm will only have to accept expression of type 0n1n and not words.

Kindly throw a light on it as it's also written in book if problem A is recognizable problem B will also be.

Comment: What problem are you referencing, from what book? What is theorem 5.3's statement? This question is very vague, please add more details, especially the specific theorem/problem you need help with.

Comment: I've given a question regarding recognizability or unrecognizability of regular TM. Regular Tm is TM which accepts a regular language . It's reduced in ATM in Sipser's book 's theorem 5.3  and I've hard time understanding that theorem.It is using ATM for reducibility which is recognizable.